# JavaScript onClick() Display

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, getelementbyid

I have an array consisting of several objects containing Strings. I am successfully able to display the array by using:

```
<td><p onclick="theMiddle(this)">The Middle</td>
```

As you see from the td tag this is part of a table. Issue is that the browser opens up a new page to display my text. I have been trying to display the array above my table in a p tag.

```
//JavaScript
var arrayTheMiddle = new Array (showName.theMiddle, beginingTime.theMiddle, 
network.abc, duration.thirty, rating.general, description.theMiddle, showImage.theMiddle);  

function theMiddle(obj){
   for(i=0; i < arrayTheMiddle.length; i++)
     {
      document.write(arrayTheMiddle[i] + "<br>");
     }
}

//HTML File

<p>Would like the array/function displayed here while the user clicks within the table below (entire table has not been listed)</p>

<td><p onclick="theMiddle(this)">The Middle</td>
```

Unfortunately I am constantly failing at utilizing get element by id to call my function which consists of an array. I have searched for all sorts of stuff, yet frankly I'm lost. Not even sure if my approach is correct at this point. I'm sure this is one of those simple things that are blowing over my head!

Comment: Is "<!DOCTYPE......."  described in your html?

Comment: EL 2002 yes it is. I have not listed the entire html here just where I was having an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strongly suggest using one of the several excellent JavaScript frameworks to do this type of work.  I  prefer Dojo, many love jQuery.

There isn't enough context here to see what is not working, but you almost always are better off avoiding document.write, which simply appends text to the HTML of the document--I don't think that is what you want in this case.

You want to create child nodes of some container node.  Normally, you would put a container node in your markup with no content for that purpose, lets call it `<div id='container'>`.

Then you would do something like this (I am far too lazy to test hand-coded DOM manipulation, but this is the idea):

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
for (var m : theMiddle) {
   if (theMiddle.hasOwnProperty(m)) {
      var txt = document.createTextNode(m);
      container.appendChild(txt); 
      var br = document.createNode('br'); // I don't approve of br, but that is not relevant here
      container.appendChild(br);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is great stuff but unfortunately I need to complete this portion in the most simplest JavaScript possible. Hence my reason for trying something like getElementbyID.

Comment: Good luck... :-)   Trust me, in my experience, using a framework is the simplest.  But if you have technical or other restrictions against it, the approach will work.

Comment: Thanks! Yep I surely agree. I have briefly used Jquery and it is quite wonderful. This is for a school project and JavaScript basics are required. :( A friend has suggested innerHTML...what do you think about that?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with innerHTML, especially for a school project where you probably only have to target one specific browser.  Often it is easier to construct a single innerHTML string than code the various individual DOM manipulations.   I vaguely recall some browser-specific gotchas, but I don't remember what they were.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions. As for using innerHTML I was successfully able to utilize it. I will post it up ASAP. I'll be trying your code soon as well. Thanks again! :)